# localStorage is not defined in angular 4

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a Guard in Angular 4 but when I try access to protected route The browser show this error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

this is my Guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class ProtectGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        console.warn("validando");
        if (localStorage.getItem('ex-token'))
            return true;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what causes it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried a restart of your computer? I can't see any problem with your code. So maybe it's just an undefined state in your development system.

Comment: I tried but this not solve my problem, thanks

Comment: Where do you run this service? client side or server? If the answer is server then my answer is: on the server side there is no localStorage existing as it has to be provided by a browser.

Comment: I'm testing a .net core project that brings an angle template, when I run the project both run on the IIS server, I do not think it's the case that the localstorage does not exist because it allows me to add an object to the localstorage (from a component), I can see it in the browser, but when I try to get (or add) an object to the localstorage from the guard I get this error

Comment: I think you are trying to get the localStorage object before you set the object into it. It's better to clarify where you are trying to set the object, is before you are get the object or not

Comment: I set the object before  to try get it

Answer (score 0):

That‘s strange. Are you able to access the item in the localStorage from another service? What I‘m thinking of is kind of a proxy service. This is just a digital scratch:

**LocalStorageService**

```
setItem(item: any, key: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
}

getItem(key: string): any {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

**Your Guard**

```
constructor (private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.warn("validando");
    if (this.localStorageService.getItem('ex-token'))
        return true;

...
```

Maybe this does the job right. Still can‘t explain why localStorage is inaccessible in your service.

Comment: They helped me with the problem I had and they told me that
"local storage was used in parts of the code that corresponded to the server"
and I had to use a third-party tool, I was recommended https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cool-storage
and it has worked. thank you very much